# Multi threading wait() notify()

Tags: java, multithreading

Can someone please tell me whats wrong with the current program

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package evenodd;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class EvenOdd {

    public static Integer i;
    public static Integer y;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EvenOdd eo = new EvenOdd();
        EvenThread et = new EvenThread(eo);
        et.setName("EvenThread");
        OddThread ot = new OddThread(eo);
        ot.setName("OddThread");
        et.start();
        ot.start();

    }
}
class EvenThread extends Thread{
    EvenOdd eo;
    public EvenThread(EvenOdd eo)
    {
        this.eo=eo;
    }
    public void run()
    {

        System.out.println("inside run "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        if(eo.y==null)
        {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EvenThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        }

        synchronized(eo)
        {

       if(eo.y==null)
       {
           eo.y=2;
           System.out.println("Even Number " + eo.y);

       }
       else if(eo.y!=null)
       {
           System.out.println("Even Number " + eo.y+2);
       }
       System.out.println("notifying "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
       eo.notify();

    }
    }

}

class OddThread extends Thread{
     EvenOdd eo;
    public OddThread(EvenOdd eo)
    {
        this.eo=eo;
    }

   public void run()
   {

       System.out.println("inside run "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
       synchronized(eo)
       {

       if(eo.i==null)
       {
           eo.i=1;
           System.out.println("Odd NUmber " + eo.i);
       }
       else if(eo.i!=null)
       {
           System.out.println("Odd NUmber " + eo.i+2);
       }
         try {
             System.out.println("waiting "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
             eo.wait();
         } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(OddThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
   }
   }
}
```

When EvenThread notifies why control is not going to OddThread. I am using teo threads to print odd and even numbers, one thread to print odd numbers and one thread to print even numbers.
First i am trying to print 1 and 2 and later increment both  values by 2.

Comment: Make `i` and `y` `volatile`, or use `AtomicInteger`. You're reading them outside of synchronized blocks.

Comment: Why are you passing an instance of `EvenOdd`? The only variables in it are static, and thus not associated with an instance.

Comment: But there isn't even an obvious reason for them to be `static`. You're passing the same instance of `EvenOdd` to both threads.

Answer (score 1):

How do you expect to add 2 if your code already passed the point of adding 2 and you dont have any loop to return there ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does exactly what you've coded it to do.

1. You start both threads
2. even goes to sleep for 200 ms
3. odd initializes the shared variable to 1, then goes to sleep waiting for even
4. even wakes up, increments the shared variable to 2, notifies, and then exits
5. odd wakes up by the notification, then exits.

If you want to endlessly print numbers, you need to loop in both threads and restructure your code a little.

Comment: Your `run()` method is not called again once the thread of your `Runnable` is awakened. It just gets resumed from immediately after the `wait()`.